# Unexpected value of a function pointer local variable

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, att

I have done some experiments in which I created a local variable of type pointer to function that points to `printf`. Then I called `printf` regularly and using that variable as following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef int (*func)(const char*,...);

int main()
{
        func x=printf;
        printf("%p\n", x);
        x("%p\n", x);
        return 0;
}
```

I have compiled it and looked at the disassembly of main using gdb and got that:

```
   0x000000000000063a <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000000063b <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000000063e <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000000642 <+8>:     mov    0x20098f(%rip),%rax        # 0x200fd8
   0x0000000000000649 <+15>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x000000000000064d <+19>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000000651 <+23>:    mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x0000000000000654 <+26>:    lea    0xb9(%rip),%rdi        # 0x714
   0x000000000000065b <+33>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000000660 <+38>:    callq  0x520 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000000665 <+43>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000000669 <+47>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
   0x000000000000066d <+51>:    mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x0000000000000670 <+54>:    lea    0x9d(%rip),%rdi        # 0x714
   0x0000000000000677 <+61>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000000067c <+66>:    callq  *%rdx
   0x000000000000067e <+68>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000000683 <+73>:    leaveq
   0x0000000000000684 <+74>:    retq
```

What is weird to me is that calling to `printf` directly uses the plt (as expected) **but** calling it using the local variable uses a whole different address (as you can see in line 4 of the assembly that the value stored in local variable x is not the address of the plt entry).

How can that be? Don't all the calls to functions undefined in the executable go first through the plt for better performance and for pic code?

Comment: Relevant https://www.technovelty.org/linux/function-pointers-and-addresses-of-functions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (as you can see in line 4 of the assembly that the value stored in local variable x is not the address of the plt entry)

Huh?  The *value* isn't visible in the disassembly, only the location it's loaded from.  (In practice it's not loading a pointer to the PLT entry, but line 4 of the assembly doesn't tell you that<sup>1</sup>.)  Use `objdump -dR` to see dynamic relocations.

That's a load from memory using a RIP-relative addressing mode.  In this case it's loading a pointer to the real `printf` address in libc.  That pointer is stored in the Global Offset Table (GOT).

To make this work, the `printf` symbol gets "early binding" instead of lazy dynamic linking, avoiding PLT overhead for later uses of that function pointer.

Footenote 1: Although maybe you were basing that reasoning on the fact that it's a load instead of a RIP-relative LEA.  That pretty much does tell you it's not the PLT entry; part of the point of the PLT is to have an address that's a link-time constant for `call rel32`, which also enables LEA with a RIP+rel32 addressing mode.  The compiler would have used that if it wanted the PLT address in a register.

---

BTW, the PLT stub itself also uses the GOT entry for its memory-indirect jump; for symbols that are only used as function call targets, the GOT entry holds a pointer back to the PLT stub, to the `push` / `jmp` instructions that invoke the lazy dynamic linker to resolve that PLT entry.  i.e. to update the GOT entry.

---

> Don't all the calls to functions undefined in the executable go first through the plt for better performance

No, the PLT *costs* runtime performance by adding an extra level of indirection to every call.  `gcc -fno-plt` uses early binding instead waiting for the first call, so it can inline the indirect `call` through the GOT right into each call site.

The PLT exists to avoid runtime fixups of `call rel32` offsets during dynamic linking.  And on 64-bit systems, to allow reaching addresses that are more than 2GB away.  And also to support **symbol interposition**.  See https://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/ (written before `-fno-plt` existed; it's basically like one of the ideas he was suggesting).

The PLT's lazy binding can improve startup performance vs. early binding, but on modern systems where cache hits are *very* important, doing all the symbol-scanning stuff at once during startup is nice.

> and for pic code?

Your code *is* PIC, or actually PIE (position-independent executable), which most distros configure GCC to do by default.

> I expected `x` to point to the address of the PLT entry of `printf`

**If you use `-fno-pie`**, then the address of the PLT entry is a link-time constant, and at compile time the compiler doesn't know whether you're going to link libc statically or dynamically.  So it uses `mov $printf, %eax` to get the address of a function-pointer into a register, and at link time that can only convert to `mov $printf@plt, %eax`.

**[See it on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include%3Cstdio.h%3E%0Atypedef+int+(*func)(const+char*,...)%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++++++func+x%3Dprintf%3B%0A++++++++printf(%22%25p%5Cn%22,+x)%3B%0A++++++++x(%22%25p%5Cn%22,+x)%3B%0A++++++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A+__attribute((visibility(%22hidden%22)))%0Aint+foo(const+char*,+...)%3B%0A%0Aint+main2()%0A%7B%0A++++++++func+x%3Dfoo%3B%0A++++++++printf(%22%25p%5Cn%22,+x)%3B%0A++++++++x(%22%25p%5Cn%22,+x)%3B%0A++++++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:30.70997561079809,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'-O3+-Wall+-fno-pie',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:35.95669105586858,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'-O3+-Wall+-fpie',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).**  (The Godbolt default is `-fno-pie`, unlike on most current Linux distros.)

```
# gcc9.2 -O3 -fpie    for your first block
        movq    printf@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rbp
        leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movq    %rbp, %rsi        # saved for later in rbp
        call    printf@PLT
```

vs.

```
# gcc9.2 -O3 -fno-pie
        movl    $printf, %esi          # linker converts this symbol reference to printf@plt
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        call    printf                 # will convert at link-time to printf@plt
      # next use also just uses mov-immediate to rematerialize, instead of saving a load result in a register.
```

So a PIE executable actually has *better* efficiency for repeated-use of function pointers to functions in standard libraries: the pointer is the final address, not just the PLT entry.

`-fno-plt -fno-pie` works more like PIE mode for taking function pointers.  Except it can still use `$foo` 32-bit immediates for the addresses of symbols in the same file, instead of a RIP-relative LEA.

```
# gcc9.2 -O3 -fno-plt -fno-pie
        movq    printf@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rbp    # saved for later in RBP
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movq    %rbp, %rsi
        call    *printf@GOTPCREL(%rip)
  # pointers to static functions can use  mov $foo, %esi
```

It seems you need `int foo(const char*,...) __attribute__((visibility("hidden")));` to tell the compiler it definitely doesn't need to go through the GOT for this symbol, with `pie` or `-fno-plt`.

Leaving it until link-time for the linker to convert `symbol` to `symbol@plt` if necessary allows the compiler to always use efficient 32-bit absolute immediates or RIP-relative addressing and only end up with PLT indirection for functions that turn out to be in a shared library.  But then you end up with pointers to PLT entries, instead of pointers to the final address.

---

If you were using Intel syntax, it would be `mov rbp, QWORD PTR printf@GOTPCREL[rip]` in GCC's output for this, if you look at asm instead of disassembly.

Looking at compiler output gives you significantly more information that just numeric offsets from RIP in plain `objdump` output.  `-r` to show relocation symbols helps some, but compiler output is generally better.  (Except you don't see that `printf` gets rewritten to `printf@plt`)

Comment: (I had this answer half-written back in June, but got side-tracked by the `-fpie` vs. `-fno-pie` behaviour difference.  Finally finished writing it. :P)

Answer (score 2):

The fourth and fifth lines of your disassembly correspond to the `func x=printf;` statement in your code.  The address of `printf` is stored in memory at address `0x200fd8`, which is accessed using a `rip`-relative address (`0x20098f(%rip)`).  This is then stored in the local variable (relative to `ebp`, at address `-0x8(%rbp)`).

Any adjustments required at run time will be made to the value stored at `0x200fd8`.

Comment: The whole purpose of the indirection added in the PLT was to do the relocation of a shared library function in a lazy fashion. I expected x to point to the address of the PLT entry of printf but instead it point to other address and there is a dynamic relocation on that address. So in that case it doesn't use the lazy feature, and that whats weird to me

Answer (score 0):

A function has one address thought the entire program, but there is a PLT for each shared library which would result in different pointers to `printf` having different values.

Comment: When you take a pointer to printf, the compiler takes the final address from the GOT so calls through that function pointer don't have to go through the PLT stub.  Note the `mov  rbp, QWORD PTR printf@GOTPCREL[rip]` in GCC's output for this, if you look at asm instead of disassembly.  https://godbolt.org/z/w1upNr